# Pass output object from Server.R to .rmd file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying out a Shinyapp which take .csv as input and calculates `mean` of the column and display the output. Also, I need to download the result in `pdf` format as report.

Issue is when I run the app it works fine and displays the result on the screen but when I try downloading the report error will be thrown stating that
 **`"Shinyoutput Objects not allowed."`**

There were few posts that I came across in SO but unable to come to a proper solution.

Below are my app.R and report.rmd file

**App.R**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", label = (" Choose Data "),multiple = F),
    actionButton("button", "Calculate Mean",style = "background-color : skyblue", 

                 icon = icon("stats", lib = "glyphicon"),width = 250 )

  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("avg", placeholder = TRUE),

    downloadButton("reportpdf", label = 'Download Report', 
                   style = "background-color : orange", width = 250)

  )
 )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  dataframe <- reactive( {

###  Create a data frame reading data file to be used by other functions..
inFile <- input$file1


if (is.null(inFile)){
  createAlert(session, "alert", "exampleAlert", title = "Oops!!!",
              content = "Please select the input file.", append = FALSE)}
else{closeAlert(session, "exampleAlert")}


data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)


 })

 avg <- eventReactive(input$button, {mean(dataframe()$A)})
 output$avg <- renderText({avg()})

  output$reportpdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
     paste('my-report', sep = '.', 'pdf')
    },


content = function(file) {
  src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

  # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
  # permission to the current working directory
  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
  on.exit(setwd(owd))
  file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

  library(rmarkdown)
  out <- render('report.Rmd', pdf_document())
  file.rename(out, file)
  params <- list(mean = output$avg)
}
 )

 }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Report.rmd**

```
 ---
 title: " Analysis Report"
 output: pdf_document
 params: mean
  ---
##Analysis Result
Percentage of data points spread: `params$mean`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use **Inline Code**.

App.R

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file1", label = (" Choose Data "),multiple = F),
  actionButton("button", "Calculate Mean",style = "background-color : skyblue", 

               icon = icon("stats", lib = "glyphicon"),width = 250 )

),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("avg", placeholder = TRUE),

  downloadButton("reportpdf", label = 'Download Report', 
                 style = "background-color : orange", width = 250)

)
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

dataframe <- reactive( {

###  Create a data frame reading data file to be used by other functions..
inFile <- input$file1


if (is.null(inFile)){
  createAlert(session, "alert", "exampleAlert", title = "Oops!!!",
              content = "Please select the input file.", append = FALSE)}
else{closeAlert(session, "exampleAlert")}


data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)


 })

  avg <- eventReactive(input$button, {mean(dataframe()$A)})

  output$avg <- renderText({avg()})

  output$reportpdf <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('my-report', sep = '.', 'pdf')
},


content = function(file) {
  src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

  # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
  # permission to the current working directory
  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
  on.exit(setwd(owd))
  file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

  library(rmarkdown)
  out <- render('report.Rmd', pdf_document())
  file.rename(out, file)

  }
 )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Report.Rmd

```
---
title: " Analysis Report"
output: pdf_document
params: mean
---
##Analysis Result
Percentage of data points spread: `r mean(dataframe()$A) `
```

Hope [this document](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) helps!!!

Comment: Finally thanks a ton, It works as expected. And that document is a consolidated cheat sheet for beginners. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SBS Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix that is by calling the reactive function instead of the variable name:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", label = (" Choose Data "),multiple = F),
      actionButton("button", "Calculate Mean",style = "background-color : skyblue", 

                   icon = icon("stats", lib = "glyphicon"),width = 250 )

    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("avg", placeholder = TRUE),

      downloadButton("reportpdf", label = 'Download Report', 
                     style = "background-color : orange", width = 250)

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataframe <- reactive( {

    ###  Create a data frame reading data file to be used by other functions..
    inFile <- input$file1


    if (is.null(inFile)){
      createAlert(session, "alert", "exampleAlert", title = "Oops!!!",
                  content = "Please select the input file.", append = FALSE)}
    else{closeAlert(session, "exampleAlert")}


    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)


  })

  avg <- eventReactive(input$button, {mean(dataframe()$A)})

   output$avg <- renderText({avg()})

  output$reportpdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', 'pdf')
    },


    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', pdf_document())
      file.rename(out, file)
      params <- list(mean = avg())
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Markdown update:

````
---
 title: " Analysis Report"
 output: pdf_document
 params: mean
  ---
##Analysis Result
Percentage of data points spread: 

```{r}
params$mean
```
````

Comment: Thanks!! Now that I am not getting the error but `params$mean` is getting printed as character instead of the value. Should I have to make any changes in the `Report.rmd` file ?

Comment: Thanks again, Its not printing the values rather its printing as `##NULL`

Comment: That could be because your mean isn't calculated properly. Could you please check that part if the dataset mean is calculated?

Comment: Mean is being displayed on the screen, it mean there is no problem with the data set or the calculation part, I am not able to fine out the reason for print `##NULL`.

Comment: Actually there is no change in code, I have copied the same code from your answer.